# Access form: How to map values for a checkbox

Tags: forms, oracle, ms-access, checkbox, mapping

I have a table in oracle. The table has an integer field with 2 possible values: null or 1. For our applications, null means false, and 1 means true.

I'm creating a form in access 2010 for that table. I want the field to be represented as a checkbox (enabled for 1, disabled for null).

If I create the checkbox directly from the field, then a null value is shown as a rectangle, and a 1 is shown correctly (as checked). But, if I change the value of the checkbox (rectangle -> checked, or checked -> unchecked), and save data to the database, then a checked value is saved as -1 (instead of 1), and an unckecked value is saved as 0 (instead of null).

If I create the checkbox from a formula:

```
Switch(my_field='1','-1',my_field Is Null,'0')
```

then the values are shown correctly, but I can't change the checkbox status (check it or unckeck it).

I think there should be an easy way to do the mapping, since it is a frequent case, but I can't find the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to work around your issue is to create a hidden TextBox control (`.Visible` = `No`) on your form. For this example I'll call it `txtMyIntAsBoolean`. It is bound to the field in your table that can contain the `Null`/`1` value.

Your (visible) Checkbox control should be unbound. It's `.Value` will be either `True` or `False` (true Boolean) depending on whether or not it is checked.

Now all you need are two lines of VBA code behind your form. Create an `On Current` event handler for the Form, and an `After Update` event handler for the Checkbox with code similar to this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub chkMyCheckbox_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtMyIntAsBoolean.Value = IIf(Me.chkMyCheckbox.Value, 1, Null)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.chkMyCheckbox.Value = (Not IsNull(Me.txtMyIntAsBoolean))
End Sub
```

The `On Current` event updates the value of the Checkbox when you move to a new record, and the `After Update` event sets the value of the hidden Text Box to the appropriate value based on the status of the Checkbox.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I think MS should add (in future versions) a way to graphically do the mapping, without the need of adding code/procedures. Something similar to the mapping in comboboxes (or even easier, since the mapping in comboboxes is a bit tricky).

Answer (score 0):

A `checkbox` can only denote `true` or `false`.

If you must use a checkbox, it will have to be unbound and it only works if `Default View` is set to `Single Form`. Otherwise, I would recommend using a combobox.

You will update the value of the control in the `On_Current` event of the form and update the value of the field in the table in the `After_Update` event of the checkbox, as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Select Case MyField
    Case 1
        MyCheckbox = True
    Case Null
        MyCheckbox = False
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub MyCheckbox_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case MyCheckbox
    Case True
        MyField = 1
    Case False
        MyField = Null
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It not easy to change the stored value returned by the checkbox.

A workarround, if you use a form, is to create an unbound checkbox and handle the AfterUpdate event.
In that event you can update a hidden bounded control with the correct value.
In the form_Current event, you can update the checkbox from the hidden control.