# Using PostgreSQL integer arrays in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, postgresql, ms-access, odbc

### Situation

My data is stored on a PostgreSQL server on my network. I've linked an ODBC data source to create linked tables to my data. The table in concern is one that is designed to track classes and their session details - including attendance. The table's design is so:

```
CREATE TABLE ClassSession
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"seq_ClassSession_id"'::regclass),
    teacher_id integer NOT NULL,
    class_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    clients_in_attendance integer[],
    date_of_session date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    CONSTRAINT "ClassSession_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

### Problem

MS Access interprets `integer[]` data types as `Short Text` (pictured below). This isn't really a big deal as long as I can match the correct format of integer enclosed in `{` and `}` - with each being separated by a `,`. An example would be: `{12,34,56,67,78}`.

Integer arrays as Short Text in Access - design view

[image]

Query example of Access interpreting integer arrays as short text/format

[image]

### Question

I was looking for some direction on how to design a form in Access that can insert data into this table while restricted to this format (using the `{`, `}`, and `,` in plaintext) without having the user type the brackets, each number, and comma to separate the `client_id` values. Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Suggest you normalize data structure instead of storing multiple data points into a single field as CSV string. Certainly code could take user selections of a multi-select listbox and concatenate to a string. There are probably other code approaches but normalization is best practice.

Comment: Unsure what you mean by normalize. Could you elaborate or point to a reference? Thank you for the response.

Comment: Google *database normalization*. This would mean another table for attendance related to ClassSession that would store a record for each clientID.

Comment: Okay, I thought that is what you meant, but was unsure. Due to that particular structure retaining a lot of redundancy - it was chosen not to store records of attendees in a separate table but an integer array. It's a bit more data efficient with the current design.

There was a lot of consideration in choosing this current design over the suggested design

Comment: Indeed. This table should be a many-to-many join with *ClientAttendance* in long format where each nested client resides in its own row with *teacher_id*, *class_name*, *date_of_session*. Very innovative, Postgres allows for extended, ANSI-plus, data types that does not fit the original relational model and other DBMS's like MS Access. Do not expect easy translation. Plus, the standard SQL will be tougher such as aggregating arrays, forcing you to only use Postgres dialect.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I will see if a redesign is possible to solve my problem. But of course, an answer for those who also went down this unmerciful path with me may still be expected. I will post an update If things progress.

Comment: Multi-select listbox already suggested. Could also use a combobox and a form public variable. Each single selection of combobox is concatenated to public variable. Difficulty with combobox is somehow preventing duplicate selection.

Comment: If you decide to stick with the PostgreSQL `integer[]` column you could also do something similar to what I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21379209/2144390) except that the hidden bound control would be a TextBox while the visible unbound control might be something like an unlinked SubForm whose Record Source is a local table with a single Long Integer column.

Comment: The correct way is to use Normalization and move the array to a table...On the other hand if you actually getting what i see in the screenshot....you could parse the field ...and using Split Command....get individual records and create 2 temp tables...a table with your data except the array and a temp table joined to 1st temp that holds the clients_in_attedance...